# Why does the compiler convert a method reference into an object that implements the functional interface?

Tags: java-8, java-stream, method-reference, functional-interface

```
    // sum of Employee salaries with DoubleStream sum method
    System.out.printf(
        "%nSum of Employees' salaries (via sum method): %.2f%n",
        list.stream()
            .mapToDouble(Employee::getSalary)
            .sum());

    // calculate sum of Employee salaries with Stream reduce method
    System.out.printf(
        "Sum of Employees' salaries (via reduce method): %.2f%n",
        list.stream()
            .mapToDouble(Employee::getSalary)
            .reduce(0, (value1, value2) -> value1 + value2));

    // average of Employee salaries with DoubleStream average method
    System.out.printf("Average of Employees' salaries: %.2f%n",
        list.stream()
            .mapToDouble(Employee::getSalary)
            .average()
            .getAsDouble());
```

Above is part of a code that puzzles me about which Streams which I'm learning right now from a book. It explains that the Stream method `mapToDouble` maps objects to `double` values and returns a `DoubleStream` and therefore we are mapping `Employee` objects to their salaries in order to calculate the `sum` and `average`.

Method `mapToDouble` receives an object that implements the functional interface `ToDoubleFunction`. This interface's `applyAsDouble` method invokes an instance method on an object and returns a `double` value. The method reference `Employee::getSalary` returns the current `Employee`'s salary as a `double`. Then the compiler converts this method reference into an object that implements the functional interface `ToDoubleFunction`.

What I don't understand is that why does the compiler need to do the conversion of the method reference into an object? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because the JVM does not support bare methods as first-class values.  There are only "objects", "arrays" and primitive values. The specification of method references in the Java language, and the implementation by the `javac` compiler are designed to work withing the constraints of the JVM / JVM spec.

Comment: Are you worried about the runtime instance, or about synthetic bytecodes generated by the compiler? For the former, @StephenC's comment should explain it, for the latter, there's a lot of magic going on with lambda factories, method handles, and if things get tricky synthetic lambda methods ... but from a user's p.o.v. should shouldn't need to worry about it.